# Bunting the ball while stepping on the plate

Tags: baseball, mlb

If a batter successfully bunts a ball while stepping on the plate, is he out?  What if the bunt is unsuccessful?

Answer (score 7):

Whether or not it's a bunt or some other hit doesn't really make a difference.  From the [official rules](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/official_info/official_rules/batter_6.jsp):

> 6.06 A batter is out for illegal action when -- (a) He hits a ball with one or both feet on the ground entirely outside the batters box.
>   Rule 6.06(a) Comment: If a batter hits a ball fair or foul while out
>   of the batters box, he shall be called out.

An unsuccessful bunt is simply a strike regardless if both feet are in or out of the batter's box.